# Lost all Likes while moving to HTTPS

Tags: facebook

I had about 30000 likes for my page and decided to move it to HTTPS, made 301 redirection from HTTP to HTTPS and found out that all Likes are lost. Switched back to HTTP but still can't get back Likes.

Facebook API show the same Likes count for both URL

Old url https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.freepdfconvert.com

and

New https url https://graph.facebook.com/https://www.freepdfconvert.com

Maybe someone knows how to get Likes back?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is use the http URL in the `og:url` tag and redirect to https with `.htaccess`.

More information can be found in this thread (and others): [Switching from HTTP to HTTPS, lost all Facebook "Likes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138193/switching-from-http-to-https-lost-all-facebook-likes)

Comment: I should put og:url meta tag and set it to http url and wait till facebook bot re-crawl web page? Now if I put og:url meta tag it changes nothing, I still get zero likes.

Comment: you don´t need to wait, you can use the debugger to refresh it: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: but to be honest, i would just use https and forget about the old likes. i mean, it´s just a number.