# Change og:url in WordPress SSL site to point to http

Tags: wordpress, facebook, ssl

I have moved to SSL recently but lost all FB likes. I have seen other answers here, I.e. [Lost all Likes while moving to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532848/lost-all-likes-while-moving-to-https) but don't know how to apply it. For example, in Simple Facebook Plugin I can see the code:

```
$fbmeta['og:url'] = esc_url($permalink);
```

How do I change that so that it gets the http version?

Comment: You mean you change https to http it make likes 0

Comment: Yes, for og:url only that is. So that it gets "old" likes from previous http version.

Comment: Really Simple SSL plugin has “force change mixed content” which meant it kept forcing every link on the site to http…

Comment: I can see "Auto replace mixed content" which is checked, but I cannot see how this relates to og:url

Comment: why you are not put that manually

Comment: This is a sort of solution for the og:url maintaining "http" but that does not entail automatically regaining Likes and it presupposes using the Yoast SEO plugin: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/move-to-ssl-losing-likes/

Comment: are you done  with this

Comment: are you switching from http to https or https to http?

Comment: Please check this person fix this issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/19139741/5212418

Comment: can you share site url??

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1: Load mix content with help of plugin**

Really Simple SSL plugin has “force change mixed content” which mean it kept forcing every link on the site to http…

**Some Features that useful**

- The mixed content scan, which shows you what you have to do if you don't have the green lock yet
- The option to enable HTTP Strict Transport Security
- The option to configure your site for the HSTS preload list
- Mixed Content Fixer for the back-end
- More detailed feedback on the configuration page.

**https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/**

**Case 2: Manually Add Facebook Open Graph Meta Data into Your WordPress Theme**

```
//Adding the Open Graph in the Language Attributes
function add_opengraph_doctype( $output ) {
        return $output . ' xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"';
    }
add_filter('language_attributes', 'add_opengraph_doctype');

//Lets add Open Graph Meta Info

function insert_fb_in_head() {
    global $post;
    if ( !is_singular()) //if it is not a post or a page
        return;
        echo '<meta property="fb:admins" content="YOUR USER ID"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_the_title() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="Your Site NAME Goes HERE"/>';
    if(!has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) { //the post does not have featured image, use a default image
        $default_image="http://example.com/image.jpg"; //replace this with a default image on your server or an image in your media library
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
    }
    else{
        $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '"/>';
    }
    echo "
";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5 );
```

**Other Solution**

First you have to change url Please check FB guide lines

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1149655968420144

You will need to instruct the facebook crawler to re-scrape your url for the changes to take effect:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing

Comment: I already have the Simple SSL plugin installed. It does not solve my problem.
In the second solution I cannot see how

Comment: echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '"/>';

Gets the http URL.

Comment: Whatever will get the FB likes back while maintaining SSL overall :)

Comment: second method add into your theme functions.php file